How can I get an input from terminal and set it to a variable in a makefile?
say I type this in the terminal: "make a_target"
my desired outcome is to have makefile with the following functionality:
TARGET = $(1)
//  a varible  set  to user input, where $(1) is the first argument after the make command I typed in the terminal.
// and of course I want to be able to use the TARGET variable later in my makefile
I saw some solutions to this. one was to type in terminal: "make TARGET=a_target" and have makefile like this:
TARGET=
but I dont want to type TARGET= in the terminal, I only want to write make a_target.
chatgpt gave me this code:
.PHONY: all

# Default target that does nothing
all:
    @echo "Specify a target as 'make <your_input>'"

# Generic rule to handle any target and set the variable
%:
    @$(eval name := $@)
    @echo "Target name is: $(name)"
    @echo "Variable 'name' is set to: $(name)"
    $(MAKE) use_name

.PHONY: use_name
use_name:
    @echo "Using the variable 'name': $(name)"

but i cannot use name as a variable later in the make file.

It seems that what you want is the predefined MAKECMDGOALS variable
The problem with chatgpt's code is that the implicit "catch-all" rule % that you are using are for implicit target. The one that do not match an existing rule.  And, if I understand correctly, what you want is to have a normal makefile, whose rules are not necessarily all that %, and still have access the the goals specified on the command line
Besides, that rule would also match secondary target, not just the one specified on command line (as long as there isn't any explicit rules)

As chrsig suggests you can use this:
TARGET := $(firstword $(MAKECMDGOALS))

However, just to be clear there is no way to prevent make from trying to BUILD this target.  In other words you can find the set of targets requested on the command line but you cannot modify it in any way.
You don't say why you want this value so maybe the above caveat is fine with you.
Make does not provide a general-purpose scripting language.  The command line arguments passed to make are for make's use, and make's use only, they are not intended to be managed by the makefile.
